# Get Array Items from back

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to get the Items from the back of Array. The function should print the values in loop. In below image you can see the there are two items missing in the pattern.

[image]

Expected Result

```
//24,25,26,27,28,29,30
//17,18,19,20,21,22,23
//10,11,12,13,14,15,16
//3,4,5,6,7,8,9
//1,2,26,27,28,29,30
```

5 and 9 Array length in not 7. The 5th number Array should have value.
`[1,2,26,27,28,29,30]` or  `[26,27,28,29,30,2,1]`. 
The same pattern should be applied to 9 number Array.

I have given it try but did not find the solution. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqbjd91L/7/)

```js
 // Setup
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30];
var arrIndex = 30;
var values

function getValues(length) {
    arrIndex = arrIndex - length;
    
    if(arrIndex<0){
      arrIndex = arr.length - Math.abs(arrIndex)
      values = arr.slice(arrIndex, arrIndex+length)
    }
    else{
        values = arr.slice(arrIndex, arrIndex+length)
    }

    var valuesCount = values.length;

    return values;
}

// Get the values
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log( getValues(7) );
}
```

Here is code which is working fine if we are getting items from the beginning of Array. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fuzewsdq/)

Comment: What is your question here ?

Comment: negative value to slice? pop (to remove them)?

Comment: I didn't really get the task. Are you trying to get the last N items and pad the result with 1, 2, 3... if the source is shorter than N?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@carlos, try with below solution ,

Problem is, here with (Array.slice) function.

You have array of 30[Index of array is valid for 0 to 29 only].
I.e  var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30];

Now when you use var arrIndex = 30, at that time; as per looping your value of Array(5) is starting from Index 25 and your array length is 7.

so here, you alternatively try to fetch value from 25 + 7 which is 31 (FYI, 31 is index).

Thus, your value = arr.slice(25,31). As we know, we don't have 30 and 31 Index in our **var arr** then definitely it is not there in value of array 5 too.

So here for solution if the slice array's endIndex is not present then we need to start up from the O Index again to get remaining element. so you need to fatch how many index are missing? [here its count =2] so we need to prevent that count and get that slice of array from (0, cnt). finally we need to concate that original array with our next array (i.e we are starting from 0)

To Resolve this below logic is written

```
  if (arrIndex < 0) {
    arrIndex = arr.length - Math.abs(arrIndex)
    var otherVal = 0;
    if (arrIndex + length >= arr.length) {
      otherVal = (arrIndex + length) - arr.length;
      values = arr.slice(arrIndex, arr.length)
    }
    if (otherVal > 0) {
      values = values.concat(arr.slice(0, otherVal))
    }
```

So your final output will be similar as per below,

```js
// Setup
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30];
var arrIndex = 30;
var values

function getValues(length) {
  arrIndex = arrIndex - length;
  if (arrIndex < 0) {
    arrIndex = arr.length - Math.abs(arrIndex)
    var otherVal = 0;
    if (arrIndex + length >= arr.length) {
      otherVal = (arrIndex + length) - arr.length;
      values = arr.slice(arrIndex, arr.length)
    }
    if (otherVal > 0) {
      values = values.concat(arr.slice(0, otherVal))
    }
  } else {
    values = arr.slice(arrIndex, arrIndex + length)
  }
  var valuesCount = values.length;
  return values;
}
// Get the values
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(getValues(7));
}
```

Comment: here you are using slice only, lets say when you come to array index  35 the it taskes value from 26 to 30. This is becuase you are using slice function which gives a array from start to and range, Not when it has value 25 in array and your given length is 7 then you are trying to get array from 25 to 32 from your original array. As your original array not consider values of 31 and 32 it shows only 5 values. So in that case you have to find till which length i can get the value. Then after if limit is over then you need to start from 0 again and get the remaining value from the start. :)

Comment: @user202729, I have edited my answer let me know if you are still unclear with any part. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a very interesting requirement, but challenge accepted :)

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30];

function getValues(length) {
  const values = [];

  let temp = [];
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    temp.unshift(arr[i]);

    if (temp.length === length) {
      values.push(temp);
      temp = [];
    }
  }

  if (temp.length > 0) {
    for (let i = arr.length - length + temp.length; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
      temp.push(arr[i]);
    }

    values.push(temp);
  }

  return values;
}

const values = getValues(7);

for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i += 1) {
  console.log(values[i]);
}
```

What's happening here is I'm looping through the array backwards and using `unshift` to create a temporary array by putting the values at the front of the array. When I collect the `length` amount for the array, I then push that array into another array, creating an array of arrays with the specified `length` value passed into the `getValues` function.

At the end of the loop, if the temporary array has anything in it, that means it wasn't able to finish creating an array of the `length` size with the remaining items at the end of the loop. So what we do then is to go to the end of the array for the remaining amount and finish the temporary array to have a final array of length `length` and push that into the final `values` array of arrays.

Comment: @user202729 updated with some explanation to make it more useful. Also, I'm not sure what your point is about not being a discussion form; that seems out of place, honestly.